# I want to write a C++ function or a C++ method able to call a pointed class method several times

Tags: c++11, pointers, generics, methods

I have several classes having methods as these:

```
class CAnswer
{
...
public:
   int16_t sendCheckReplies(const char send[], uint16_t timeout, ...)
   {
      return 64;
   }
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------

   bool sendCheckReply(const char *send, const char *reply, uint16_t timeout)
   {
      getReply(send, timeout);
      return checkReply(reply, timeout);
   }
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------

   // Send prefix, suffix, and newline.  Verify FONA response matches reply parameter.
   bool sendCheckReply(const char* prefix, char *suffix, const char* reply, uint16_t timeout)
   {
      getReply(prefix, suffix, timeout);
      return checkReply(reply, timeout);
   }
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
};
```

and instead to modify each method as:

```
   bool sendCheckReply(const char *send, const char *reply, uint16_t timeout, int count)
   {
      for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
      {
          getReply(send, timeout);  // puts the reply in _replybuffer[1500];
          if(true == checkReply(reply, timeout))
              return true;
          delay(2);
      }
      return false;
   }
   //------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to write something like:

```
int main(void)
{
   CAnswer answer;
   bool bret = false;
   bret = repeatUntil(true, answer.sendCheckReply("ATV0", "OK", 1000), 5);
   std::cout << "bret: " << bret << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

repeatUntil() should have a signature similar to:

```
    bool repeatUntil(bool bretOk, bool (CAnswer::*pM)(), int iCount)

where:
  bretOk: is the value should be returned by the method pointed by pM because repeatUntil returns true; 
  count: is the maximum number of trials pM can be called if doesn't return bretOk.
```

Of course the problem is that the signature of the pointer to the method is not always the same and I would write a C++ function as general as possible.

I have a C++11/14 compatible compiler. Is there anything similar to a "generic method pointer" introduced by C++11/14 or do I need to use templates? Or is there anything better than a template in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: "repeatUntil() should have a signature similar to:" Please define _similar_.

Comment: in this context I mean the signature may be more or less that I wrote mut it is not a must